# how to add onmouseover method in Jade/Pug?

Tags: pug

tr
th Name
th Login
th Roles
tbody
each user in usersData
tr
td= user.name
td= user.login
td
each role in Object.keys(user.roles.sort())
div= user.roles[role]

Answer (score 0):

Add a script to the page which adds these event handlers.